# py.test command is not working on python3.10 in mac

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I tried to run py.test command to run the whole test cases in the current folder.
but it is giving the below error:

```bash
swat@C02F6M testcases % py.test           
zsh: command not found: py.test

------------------------------------
```

Whereas the below command is working fine. Why is the above py.test command not working?

```bash
swat@C02F6M testcases % python3 -m py.test 

================================ test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/swat/PycharmProjects/SampleProject, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: json-report-1.5.0, metadata-2.0.2
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                         

test_validateCount.py ..                                                                                                                                            [100%]

=================================== 2 passed in 0.01s =====================================
```

Comment: you should be invoking it by running pytest, digging in to why the old way does or doesn’t work is pointless since it’s only around for backwards compatibility. you can read more here —> https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1629#issue-161422224

Comment: Just making sure this is super clear - the correct command was changed from `py.test` to just `pytest` 6 years ago, and the earlier version is no longer supported - try just running `pytest` and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: It is same with pytest also.

$Python3 -m pytest is working fine where as $pytest is not working.

The issue might be : even though pytest is already installed in my machine, pytest folder is not getting displayed in venv -> lib -> Site-packages folder.
how can I get this.